# C++ - Function returns, but doesn't hand back control

Tags: c++, linux

I'm working on yet another socket library for Linux in C++, just as a personal exercise. 
Here's my code:

```
#ifndef SOCKET_H
#define SOCKET_H

#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

/**
 * Creates a struct to hold all the necessary information to create a socket.<br/>
 * Typically, you should not need to call this yourself, as it is done when you     call         listen() or dial()
 * @param host The hostname or IP address to connect to.
 * @param service The service on that machine (e.g "http" or "80")
 * @param sock The type of socket ("tcp" or "udp")
 * @return A addrinfo struct with all the required information to create a connection.
 */
addrinfo setup(const char *host,const char *service,const char *sock) {
    struct addrinfo hints;
    struct addrinfo *serv;
cout << "2.call to setup()\n";
//cout << "3.setup() returns here.\n";
//return *serv;
    int status=0;
/*struct addrinfo hints;
    struct addrinfo *serv;*/

    memset(&hints,0,sizeof hints);
    hints.ai_family=AF_UNSPEC;
    if (sock=="tcp") {
    hints.ai_socktype=SOCK_STREAM;
    } else if (sock=="udp") {
        hints.ai_socktype=SOCK_DGRAM;
    } else {
        fprintf(stderr,"[!] xsockets: error: unknown socket type %s\n",sock);
        exit(2);
    }
    hints.ai_flags=AI_PASSIVE;

    if ((status=getaddrinfo(host,service,&hints,&serv))!=0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "[!] xsockets: error: getaddrinfo error: %s\n",     gai_strerror(status));
        exit(1);
    }
    cout << "3.setup() returns here.\n";
    return *serv;
}

/**
 * Listens on a portand returns a scoket file descriptor.
 * @param service The service on this machine (e.g "http" or "80")
 * @param sock The type of socket ("tcp" or "udp")
 * @return A socket filde descriptor.
 */
int listen(const char *service,const char *sock) {
    cout << "1.call to listen()\n";
    struct addrinfo *serv;
    *serv=setup(NULL,service,sock);
    cout << "4.is this ever called?";
    int sockfd=socket(serv->ai_family,serv->ai_socktype,serv->ai_protocol);
    int status=bind(sockfd,serv->ai_addr,serv->ai_addrlen);
    if (status!=0) {
        fprintf(stderr,"[!] xsockets: error: bind error:                         %s\n",gai_strerror(status));
        exit(3);
}
    cout << "5.listen() returns here.";
    return sockfd;
}
#endif
```

If I run this, it gets up to #3 "setup() returns here" but never goes to #4 "is this ever called?" much less #5 "listen() returns here"

Can anyone tell me what went wrong.

I'm on a Ubuntu Linux, running this with root privileges. It was compiled with the `g++` command.

Here's what I'm getting:

Comment: First off, use a debugger not print statements.  Second, it probably gets there but the output buffer doesn't flush before something else causes a failure - you can flush() to force this, and I think you can cout << endl, though I'm not sure if that'll do it.  Third, you should describe what behavior you actually do see.  That's jsut as important as the expected behavior when diagnosing a bug.

Comment: Instead of cout, use std::cerr so that anything you write to it is immediately flushed.

Comment: Why are you returning an `addrinfo` struct by-value?  You should be returning a pointer.  You're also leaking memory—you must call `freeaddrinfo()` on the value returned by `getaddrinfo()` (and *not* on a copy of the underlying `addrinfo` structure).

Comment: Oh. That makes sense now.

Answer (score 3):

You have undefined behaviour because you do not initialize the pointer `serv` but then immediately dereference it with `*serv`.

Nonetheless, when you are debugging, you should ensure that the output is flushed by inserting `std::flush` or `std::endl` into `std::cout`:

```
cout << "4.is this ever called?" << std::endl;
```

Comment: Oh yeah, I was doing that because I thought it might have something to do with something between the call of setup() and the return of listen(). Even with that, it, and the flushing, it still does not work.

Comment: … or just use `std::cerr` instead of `std::cout` which auto-flushed for exactly such situations.

Answer (score 2):

You have some basic problems:

1. You don't allocate memory for `serv`.

   `struct addrinfo *serv;`

   `*serv=setup(NULL,service,sock);`
2. you don't check the return values of most functions e.g `int
   sockfd`.
3. You declare things on stack and not globaly, try to figure out what
   is the scope of each variable.

   ```
   struct addrinfo hints;
   struct addrinfo *serv;
   ```